# Sending message to Azure IoT hub partition

Tags: azure, iot, servicebus, partition, azure-iot-hub

Does anyone know if there is a library that allows you to send a message to a specific partition on an IoT hub with Azure.
I was previously able to achieve this with azuresblite library, unfortunatelly which I Cannot use.
https://github.com/ppatierno/azuresblite

Comment: There are no partitions in IoT Hub.

Comment: @CSharpRocks , Are you sure? when you create IoT Hub it asks you for a partition count. you can also see the number of partition in the end points tab

Comment: You're right, I was thinking about Units.  I'm not sure you can specify the partition from the sender.  Have you looked at this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted

Comment: @CSharpRocks you cannot specify partitions when you **send** messages to the IoT Hub. You read the part **receive message from IoT Hub** where you can specify from which partition you want to read.

Comment: Thanks @astaykov!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to send a message to a specific partition. Period.
Partitions are used internally to allow scaling of the IoT (Event Hub) and allow for scaling out the consumer app (the one that reads the events out of the Hub).

While you can specify a Partition Key when using Event Hub, this does identify a Partition ID. And using IoT Hub, the option to specify Partition Key is anyway hidden and you cannot influence it. Specifying a Partition Key for a message in **Event Hub** will just make sure that all messages with the same partition key will fall into the same partition. But you cannot tell which partition (0,1,2..n). I have seen projects which try to literary abuse the Partitions and use them as "tenants". Very wrong way of completely abusing scalability of Event Hubs.

Please do not abuse the partitioning of Event Hub (which is anyway the back-end system for an IoT Hub). Do not force Partition Keys. Thus you are unbalancing the Event Hub and may go into a wrong direction. Instead please clearly define a technical issue you are trying to solve and we may be able to help you.

Comment: Is there any way to segregate data within iot hub for multiple tenants? I had an idea to use topics in MQTT, but that is not possilbe for consuming data using an Event Processor Host

Answer (score 1):

Azure IoT Hub ensures proper ordering of messages while messages are read from IoT Hub. PF the link for more details - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#ordering-guarantees-with-at-least-once-delivery

Comment: Also i found that -
For a given device ID, the IoT hub uses a hash of the device ID to determine which partition to store its messages. This will also help ensure proper ordering while reading the messages from the IoT Hub.<https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-amqp-support>